# How to download AMI from Amazon EC2 .?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I would like to download a Amazon EC2 AMI

Can i know the procedure for downloading a AMI from Amazon EC2 account.

How do I do this?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=131841

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/